# Api Gateway Android SDK NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

We're looking to implement our **AWS API Gateway generated Android SDK** in our app.

When we try to build our client class, we get the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:Lcom/amazonaws/util/json/DateDeserializer;`

Here's how we create our client instance:

```
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
final CigarSocialClient client = factory.build(CigarSocialClient.class);
```

We have been searching for a solution but haven't found anything yet. The best solution seems to ditch the generated sdk and invoke our api gateway via web requests.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

We're using the following [aws tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html)

Here is our `build.gradle` file for the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+'
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

> D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/util/json/DateDeserializer;
>                at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.(ApiClientHandler.java:59)
>                at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.getHandler(ApiClientFactory.java:145)
>                at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.build(ApiClientFactory.java:123)
>                at com.example.API.testApiGatwaySdk(API.java:125)
>                at com.example.ListFragment$override.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:60)
>                at com.example.ListFragment$override.access$dispatch(ListFragment.java)
>                at com.example.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:0)
>                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1272)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
>                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:600)
>                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
>                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6929)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4974)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
>                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
>                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.amazonaws.util.json.DateDeserializer" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.0_f4e9ad562a860d98fa5881a52f2737573a46b23e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_d08c5958e93c18231cddf69dc14d83b8ae6d3fa3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_ce51fbf88aa3b5412a363fc449e8164899b38118-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_982f26845e74cf0a28b29b365

Comment: Release or debug build?

Comment: I believe this is a debug build. I'm a bit new to android but I can see the output apk has the `app-debug.apk` filename.

Comment: Ok can you add you build.gradle file please

Comment: Updated the question with the build.gradle file. Our sdk is inside our app/libs folder.

Comment: And full stacktrace please :)

Comment: You got it! See above

Comment: try removing  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs'), since you gonna pull all of dependencies with gradle

Comment: Removing those lines will causes the following error: `Error:(5, 49) error: package com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway does not exist` This is because our generated SDK lives inside the app/libs folder as described in the aws tutorial link above.

Comment: what about removing those last 2 lines?

Comment: Still see the error after removing those bottom 2 lines. I was starting to think it had something to do with compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+' & compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+'  referring to sdk version 2.2 instead of version 2.4.2. The 2.4.2 version is included in the .zip after I generate and download my sdk in the aws api gateway console.

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic I tried it again after restarting android studio and now I get this error:  `ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration;
                      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.getHandler(ApiClientFactory.java:143)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.build(ApiClientFactory.java:123)`

Comment: SO I resolved the above error by adding the `aws-android-sdk 2.4.2` as a dependency. Now I'm getting this error:  `com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException:  (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)`

Comment: lol AWS... il try to add sdk myself and get back to you, in the meantime try going throught their closed issues on github

Comment: haha okay thank you. I'll keep trying to break ground over here

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of `aws-android-sdk-core` that is very old and not compatible with the altest clients generated by API gateway. Please update the sdk to the latest.